# Twilio - sending sms doesn't call the statusCallback URL

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-node

Twilio free account.
This is how I send the message:

```
      const args = {
        from : TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
        to   : '+15005550006', // magic test number
        body : "test",
        statusCallback: 'https://postb.in/1604476976671-5019259769469' //twilioCallback.getUrl()
      }
      message = await this.client.messages.create(args)
```

Results: postbin never receives a request. nor does my own twilio callback url. Do I need to subscribe, create a messaging service, pay for a sender phone number, and use that messaging service id in the `args`? Does that make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Magic numbers / test credentials don’t send requests. Use your production Account SID and Auth Token and a real Twilio number to send the request.

[Why aren't my test credentials working?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183808-Why-aren-t-my-test-credentials-working-)